# Strange things with tkinter's canvas.after()

Tags: python, tkinter

Ive been having some issues where if the shot is fired multiple times before it leaves the canvas it will speed up each time it is redrawn until its faster than the canvas can update it. Ive attributed the problem to the canvas.after command because if I impliment this as a while loop using the time.sleep command it works fine (unfortunately I can use the implementation of the code because  it works as two separate loops)

```
#imports
from tkinter import *


#The Game
class Game:
def __init__(self):

    #creating the static canvas background
    self.window = Tk()
    self.window.title('Shoot your friends')
    self.canvas = Canvas(width= 900,
                      height= 900,
                      cursor= 'circle')
    self.canvas.pack()

    self.canvas.create_line(450, 900,
                       450, 0, 
                       dash = (10))

    self.p1_ship = PhotoImage(file = "red_ship.gif")
    self.p2_ship = PhotoImage(file = "blue_ship.gif")
    self.p1_laser = PhotoImage(file = "red_laser.gif")
    self.p2_laser = PhotoImage(file = "blue_laser.gif")        

    #Buttons at the bottom
    self.frame = Frame(self.window)
    self.frame.pack()

    #Determining the state of edge teleporting and toggling it
    self.etb = True
    def et():
        if self.etb == True:               
            self.etb = False
            Et["text"] = "Turn On Edge Teleporting"
        else:
            self.etb = True
            Et["text"] = "Turn Off Edge Teleporting"

        print ("Edge Telepoting Toggled")


    Et = Button(self.frame, text="Turn Off Edge Teleporting", command = et, cursor= 'double_arrow')
    Et.grid(row=0,column=0)

    self.Rfb = False
    def rf():
        if self.Rfb == True:               
            self.Rfb = False
            Rf["text"] = "Turn On Rapid Fire "
        else:
            self.Rfb = True
            Rf["text"] = "Turn Off Rapid Fire"

        print ("Rapid Fire Toggled")


    Rf = Button(self.frame, text="Turn On Rapid Fire", command = rf, cursor= 'cross')
    Rf.grid(row=0,column=1)

    def restart():
        print ('restart')
    restart_b = Button(self.frame, text="Restart Game", command = restart, fg='Blue', bg= 'red', cursor='exchange' )
    restart_b.grid(row=0,column=2)

    self.y_p1 = 400
    self.y_p2 = 400

    self.ship_p1 = self.canvas.create_image(40, 450, image=self.p1_ship)             
    self.ship_p2 = self.canvas.create_image(860, 450, image=self.p2_ship) 



    self.canvas.move(self.ship_p1,0,0)
    self.canvas.move(self.ship_p2,0,0)


# Functions that handle movement of the ships taking into account multiple variables

    #For example If edge teleporting is ON the ship will teleport to the top of the screen if        it is at the bottom and the down key is pressed and vice versa
    #My implementation of this may not be the most efficient but I like the options it gives     me for adding future features and it looks cool.
    def p1_up(event):
        if self.etb == True and self.y_p1 >= 100:
            self.canvas.move(self.ship_p1,0,-100)
            self.y_p1 += -100                
        elif self.etb == True:
            self.canvas.move(self.ship_p1,0,+800)
            self.y_p1 += +800                
        elif self.y_p1 >= 100:
            self.canvas.move(self.ship_p1,0,-100)
            self.y_p1 += -100


    def p1_down(event):
        if self.etb == True and self.y_p1 <= 799:
            self.canvas.move(self.ship_p1,0,+100)
            self.y_p1 += 100                
        elif self.etb == True:
            self.canvas.move(self.ship_p1,0,-800)
            self.y_p1 += -800
        elif self.y_p1 <= 799:
            self.canvas.move(self.ship_p1,0,+100)
            self.y_p1 += 100


    def p2_up(event):
        if self.etb == True and self.y_p2 >= 100:
            self.canvas.move(self.ship_p2,0,-100)
            self.y_p2 += -100  
        elif self.etb == True:
            self.canvas.move(self.ship_p2,0,+800)
            self.y_p2 += +800
        elif self.y_p2 >= 100:
            self.canvas.move(self.ship_p2,0,-100)
            self.y_p2 += -100


    def p2_down(event):
        if self.etb == True and self.y_p2 <= 799:
            self.canvas.move(self.ship_p2,0,+100)
            self.y_p2 += 100
        elif self.etb == True:
            self.canvas.move(self.ship_p2,0,-800)
            self.y_p2 += -800
        elif self.y_p2 <= 799:
            self.canvas.move(self.ship_p2,0,+100)
            self.y_p2 += 100

    # Functions for shooting

    self.p1_shot_out = False
    self.p2_shot_out = False

    def p1_shoot(event):

        if self.p1_shot_out == True:  
            self.canvas.delete(self.laser_p1)
        #draws the laser    
        self.laser_p1 = self.canvas.create_image(50, self.y_p1 +50, image=self.p1_laser)
        self.x_p1_laser = 50
        self.p1_shot_out = True

        self.window.after(1, p1_shoot_move)


    def p1_shoot_move():
        #moves the laser until its outside the canvas
        if self.x_p1_laser >= 930:
            pass
        else:
            self.canvas.move(self.laser_p1,5,0)
            self.x_p1_laser += 5 
            self.canvas.update()
            self.window.after(3, p1_shoot_move)


    def p2_shoot(event):
        if self.p2_shot_out == True:
            self.canvas.delete(self.laser_p2)
        #draws the laser
        self.laser_p2 = self.canvas.create_image(750, self.y_p2 +50, image=self.p2_laser)
        self.x_p2_laser = 750
        self.p2_shot_out = True

        self.window.after(4, p2_shoot_move)


    def p2_shoot_move():
        #moves the laser until its outside the canvas
        if self.x_p2_laser <= -110:
            pass
        else:
            self.canvas.move(self.laser_p2,-5,0)
            self.x_p2_laser += -5 
            self.canvas.update()
            self.window.after(4, p2_shoot_move)



    # Key bindings that trigger their respective functions
    self.canvas.bind('w', p1_up)
    self.canvas.bind('s', p1_down)        
    self.canvas.bind('<Up>', p2_up)
    self.canvas.bind('<Down>', p2_down)
    self.canvas.bind('<space>', p1_shoot)
    self.canvas.bind('<Control_R>', p2_shoot)



    self.canvas.focus_set()
    # this mainloop thing is some sort of witchcraft! OH MY!!!
    self.window.mainloop()
```

Game()

Comment: I am not sure if it's a good thing to use `time.sleep` with `tkinter`

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Only one of p1, p2 is needed to test, but more is needed to test.

Comment: @nbro time.sleep is generally a bad idea, but I don't think it is the problem here, since only done once per projectile.

Comment: @Terry Jan Reedy The time.sleep() meathod is something i forgot to convert after testing it out with a while loop. I changed it to window.after()

Comment: @TerryJanReedy So I should include the rest of the class?

Comment: I just include the whole class so the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: I would think that 3 milliseconds is not enough time for the canvas to redraw, so set "after" to 30 and see what happens.  Your indentation is too screwed to make sense of the program.  Take a look at the code under def restart and the code at the very bottom.

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect in the code example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that each time you "shoot", you call `after`. If you "shoot" five times in rapid succession, you'll have 5 "moves" queued up. Each adds 5 to the x location, and they all will run just a few ms apart, so the laser will appear to be moving very fast. The five will run in rapid succession, then 3ms later they will run in rapid succession again, and so on.

What you need to do is keep a reference to the thing you schedule with `after`, and cancel it before starting a new shot. That, or keep an independent record of the x/y coordinate for each shot if you want more than one shot being active at a time.

For example:

```
def p1_shoot(event):
    ....
    # cancel any previous shot
    if self.p1_job is not None:
        self.window.after_cancel(self.p1_job)
    self.p1_job = self.window.after(1, p1_shoot_move)
```

Of course, you need to set `self.p1_job` every time you call after, and you need to initialize it to None at the start, and when the bullet is destroyed.